# How to pass text input to MultinomialNB classifier after Saving the Model

Tags: python, text-classification

My test input is "SriRam"
This need to be classified using ML model whether its a Male name or female

So After saving the model

```
import joblib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
Gender_model = open('Gender_model.pkl','rb')
clf = joblib.load(Gender_model)
```

Input = "sriRam"

How to pass this input to CLf in the above code

Thanks

Comment: You're probably looking for the `predict` function. But I'm not sure that you understand how a classification model works, since you don't appear to have any features.